# Extract SAS Enterprise Guide into Unix Server runnable batch?

Tags: linux, batch-file, sas, enterprise

We have built a project in Enterprise Guide for the purpose of creating a easy understandable and maintainable code. The project contain a set of process flows which run should be done in specific order. This project we need to run on a Linux Server machine, where the SAS Metadata Server is running.
Basic idea is to extract this project into SAS code, which we would be able to run from command line in Linux as a batch job.

#### Question 1:

1. Is there any other way to schedule a batch job in Linux-hosted SAS Server? I have read about VBS scripting for scheduling/running batch jobs, but in order this to be done on Linux Server, a installation of WINE is required, which on a production machine which already runs a number of other important applications, is almost completely out of question.
2. Is there a way to specify a complete project export into SAS code, provided that I give the specific order of running process flows? I have tried out ordered list, which is able to make you a list of tasks to run in order (although there is no way to choose a whole process flow as a single task), but unfortunately, this ordered list itself is later not possible to be exported as a SAS code.

Current solution we do is the following:
We export each single process flow of the SAS EG project into SAS code, and then create another SAS code with %include lines to run all the extracted codes in order that we want. This is of course a possible solution, but definitely not the most elegant one.

#### Question 2:

1. Since I don't know how exactly the code is being exported afterwards, are there any dangers I should bear in mind with the solution I chose.
2. Is there any other, more elegant way?

Comment: Not an answer, but this might help. If you rename the .egp (project file) as a .zip, you can then view the contents of the EG Project (usually .sas files containing the code and XML files describing flows).

Comment: I have the users export to one of the folders "Daily", "Hourly", "Weekly" or "Monthly". They also need to maintain an Excel workbook with the job names. I then have a job that loops through the jobs in the Excel workbook and submit them using X command. The return code (&SYSRC) of the job is collected and a summary email is sent when it is finnished.

Comment: There is one problem with the exported code, the length of the lines might get too long. there is a "bug" in EG that might create lines longer than ~250 characters in a line. I don't remember the exact number, but a batch job can only have ~250 characters. The users that export the project should be notified about this, so they can "break" the lines.

Comment: Here is the SAS Note that describes the problem with submitting lines longer than 256 characters in batch: http://support.sas.com/kb/15/883.html

Comment: Post 9.2 you should set the LRECL system option to much longer than 256 and you won't have to worry about that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options from what I'm familiar with, plus I suspect if Dom happens by he'll know more.  These answers are based on EG 6.1, which is the current version (ships with 9.4); it's possible some of these things may not be true in earlier versions.

First, if you're running Enterprise Guide from Windows, you can schedule the job locally (on any Windows machine with Enterprise Guide).  You're not scheduling the server directly, you schedule Windows to launch an EG process that connects to the server and does its magic.  That's how I largely interact with scheduling (because I have a fairly 'light' scheduling need).

Second, from the blog post ["Four Ways to Schedule SAS Tasks"](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2013/08/14/four-ways-to-schedule-sas-tasks/), options 3 and 4 may be helpful for you.  The SAS Platform Suite is designed in part for scheduling, and the options using SAS Management Console to schedule via operating system tools, are both very helpful.

Third, you may want to look into SAS Stored Processes, which should be schedulable.  A process flow can be converted into a stored process.

---

For your specific questions:

- Question 1: When you export a process flow or a project, at least in 6.1 you have the option to change the order in which the programs are exported.  It's manual, so it's probably not perfect, but it does give you that option.  (The code seems to be by default in creation order, which is sub-optimal.)  The project export does group process flows together, but you don't have the option of manipulating the order of process flows - you have to move each program around, which would be tedious.  It also of course gives you less flexibility if you need to multiply run programs.
- Question 2: As Stig Eide points out in comments, make sure your System Option LRECL is > 256 (the default) or you run some risk of code being cut off.  In 9.2+ this is modifiable; just place `LRECL=32767`in your config.sas file.

Comment: thanks, LRECL is a really good hint. I am not sure if SAS EG Export features takes care of its own created query about that issue, but I will use it as a precaution measure.

Thank you all for your answers!